# How to get values of JSON object to string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, object

I have a JSON object. For example:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname",
    "number": "111111111"
}
```

How to make a string from this JSON object using javascript, that looks like this.

> Name Surname 111111111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement to iterating values of object. In loop add every value to string.

```js
var json = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname",
    "number": "111111111"
};

var str = "";
for (var key in json) {
    str += (key != "id") ? (json[key] + " ") : "";
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Supossing that you have this json stored in a var.
for example:

```
var jsonObject = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname",
    "number": "111111111"
}
```

You can do something like that:

```
var myStringResult = jsonObject.name + ' ' + jsonObject.surname + ' ' + jsonObject.number;
```

Comment: Yes that would be nice, but I need more universal approach, because I may get JSON object with different label names

Comment: You can use this function: JSON.stringify.
Documentation here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify